# Multiples authentication methods for Postgresql

Tags: ldap, authentication, postgresql

I presently use "md5" authentication for access from the lan:

`host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        md5`

I want to add ldap authentication method, so I added this line before:

`host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        ldap "ldap://192.168.1.2/basedn;uid=;,cn=xx,dc=yy,dc=zz,dc=ca"`

This work great with ldap accounts, but if I try to login with an account not present on the LDAP server, the login fails (postgresql doesn't try the md5 authentication).

There is a way to support more than one authentication method with postgresql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No -- `Since the pg_hba.conf records are examined sequentially for each connection attempt, the order of the records is significant.` -- In other words "First match is the method I'm going to use".
You would have to explicitly list all the local (`md5`) accounts before proceeding to the "all users" LDAP authentication in order for this to work (and that starts to get hairy with maintaining the `pg_hba.conf` file).

As a workaround you can use the `pam` authentication method, and configure PAM's "postgres" service to use whatever methods you wish (including falling back to alternate methods), but this limits you to whatever PAM modules are installed/configured on your system.
(For suitably broad definitions of "limits" -- e.g. you could use one-time passwords for Postgres accounts if you use PAM as the authentication method).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I defined this rule:

`host    all         @pgUsers  192.168.1.0/24        md5`

and created a pgUsers file to define user to authenticate against pg authentication instead of ldap.  Seem to work great.

Comment: Also a good solution -- the only downside I see is that it doesn't buy you the (potential for) single sign-on like LDAP would.

Comment: I still use LDAP for authenticating my users.  I use postgresql auth only for users account used by web applications because I don't want to create them LDAP accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem; I wanted to use `md5` for an application user and `ldap` for other users in my organization. One difference is that I am using the official Docker Postgres image, but my method should still work for the regular Postgresql users.

The Docker Postgres image comes with a `postgres` user by default. You can add a specific user to your `pg_hba.conf` file by pre-pending the username with a plus sign `+`.

My pg_hba.conf ended up being the following:

```
local all all                    trust
host  all all       127.0.0.1/32 trust
host  all all       ::1/128      trust
host  all +postgres all          md5
host  all all       all          ldap ldapurl="ldap://192.168.1.2:389/ou=People,dc=Company,dc=com?uid?one"
```

The second to last line there supports the application user, `postgres`, and the last line there supports multiple LDAP user accounts.

Comment: AFAIK the +abcd notation does not mean "add a specific user" but "allow ANY local user in the group abcd".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

local   all             postgres                                peer

host    all             user1,user2     0.0.0.0/0               ldap ldapserver=192.168.0.1 ldapbasedn="DC=domain,DC=local" ldapbinddn="admin@domain" ldapbindpasswd="*******" ldapsearchattribute="sAMAccountName"

local   all             all                                     peer

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

host    all             all             10.10.10.2/32           trust #Don't mind this line...